# Resources for a Deep Dive into the New Keynesian / DSGE models

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, reference-request, dsge, new-keynesian-economics

I would like to deep dive into new Keynesian models and DSGE models. Do you know comprehensive resources that cover both the mathematical and economic requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Wickens Macroeconomic Theory: A Dynamic General Equilibrium Approach, is good resource that has what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion

Comment: I don't agree. That textbook is infamous for its many typos.

Comment: @jpfeifer there were few typos in the first printing but it’s still considered one of the best introductions to subject matter, also I don’t have new edition but I would be surprised if they wouldn’t be corrected

Comment: @1muflon1 At least for the first edition, a completely wrong chapter had monetary non-neutrality in a flex price model due to wrong algebra. Official and unofficial errata (https://www.blogs.uni-mainz.de/fb03-economics-macro/files/2018/11/Wickens_Errata_List_2.pdf) was more than 20 pages. For the second edition, I had 1.5 pages of mistakes after reading the first 50 pages of the book and then gave up. For that edition, there is no errata list online.

Comment: @Maurizio Marinaro : sometimes going to the website of a faculty member and going through his-her course notes can be better than any book. I don't know if this is true in this case but here's a link that looks pretty useful at a glance. https://sites.google.com/site/pfeiferecon/teaching

Comment: Thank for your further support. This is really valuable. I will also try to see on other teachers' websites and examine their notes.